# Textcomplete in textarea is not working in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, editor, handlebars.js

I've been trying to use `jquery-textcomplete` https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete in my text editor for **emoji**.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2b2L4ur6/2/. Emoji appears but I don't know why `jquery-textcomplete` is not working. It does not suggest a list of emojis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast found a solution. I used `didInsertElement` and `Ember.run.next()` in side a `TextArea` Component. Here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hasib/2b2L4ur6/4/.